# Django Get() Returned More Than One Object

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am receiving the following error:

get() returned more than one Manifests -- it returned 2!

I understand this is because there are multiple records in the database with the same value, but I want to return ALL of those records, so I assume I need to use something other than .get but I'm not sure what/how.

```
def write_pdf_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs') 
        y = Orders.objects.all()
        z = Manifests.objects.all()
        order = y.get(reference=reference)
        manifest = z.get(reference=reference)

....

....

#Manifest
    p.drawString(30,620,'MANIFEST: ')
    p.drawString(30,605,manifest.description)
```

The issue is the manifest.description line.  There are more than one records with the same "reference" in the database, and so they won't print.  So my question is 2 parts:

1) how can I change manifest = z.get(reference=reference) so that I can access multiple records

2) how can I then access those records in place of "manifest.description"

Comment: use `z.filter()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question you can use `filter()`method for getting specific records from your model.

```
def write_pdf_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs') 
        manifest = Manifests.objects.filter(reference=reference)
        order = Orders.objects.get(reference=reference)
```

For your second question, `filter()` returns a queryset.So you can access the data by iterating over the queryset or by the index.

```
for data in manifest:
  print(data.description)
```

> For your information get() returns an object and throws an exception if no object is found while filter() returns an empty list.

Comment: this works! thank you for your detailed answer.  However, since I am using report lab in this instance:

```
 p.drawString(30,620,'MANIFEST: ')
 p.drawString(30,605,manifest.description)
```

do you know of a way that I could make the second manifest description go to the next line down, and the next manifest line on the next line down? Because using the for loop just prints each description out on top of the other.

Answer (score 2):

`get` expected to returns *single item* with desired criteria, else (nothing or more than one) raise an exception. If you want to select *any number of items* with desired criteria, you can use `filter` instead.

```
def write_pdf_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs') 
        manifest_queryset = Manifests.objects.filter(reference=reference)
        order = Orders.objects.get(reference=reference)
```

Then you can iterate the selected manifests and get the value of each manifest related field by using *dot notation*.

```
for manifest in manifest_queryset:
    print(manifest.description)
```

Also you can get list of descriptions by using `values_list`.

```
description_list = manifest_queryset.values_list('description', flat=True)
```

You can get more information in [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/).

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple data you can use the **filter** property.

```
order = Orders.objects.all().filter(reference=reference)
manifest = Manifest.objects.all().filter(reference=reference)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` instead of `get()`.

But the filter returns **queryset** not **object**. So you have to loop through queryset.

```
def write_pdf_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs') 
       y = Orders.objects.all()
       z = Manifests.objects.all()
       order = y.get(reference=reference)
       manifest = z.filter(reference=reference)
       for manifest_value in manifest:
           print(manifest_value.description)
```

For more details about queryset see [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api)

Answer (score 0):

to get specific item by unique fields you can use `get`. will raise `DoesNotExist` if no object found.

```
order = Orders.objects.get(pk=reference)
```

if you want list of objects use `filter`. will default to `[]` if can't find any.

```
manifest = Manifest.objects.filter(reference=reference)
```